# How to add Bootstrap class to Ransack form_for

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bootstrap-5, ransack

In views/articles/index.html.erb:

```
<%= search_form_for  @q  do |f| %>
  <%= f.label :title %>
  <%= f.search_field :title_or_body_cont_any %>
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

I tried add class="btn btn-primary" to submit:

```
<%= f.submit,class="btn btn-primary"  %>
```

but I get error. How can I join Bootstrap class to form_for field?

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, `search_form_for` is usual form [wrapper](https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/ransack/blob/main/lib/ransack/helpers/form_helper.rb#L34)

Therefore it's usual [submit](https://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormBuilder.html#method-i-submit) and it's enough to pass class as option:

```rb
<%= f.submit class: "btn btn-primary"  %>
```

Comment: It don't works. Encountered a syntax error while rendering template

Comment: syntax error. unexpected label, expecting '=' append = ( f.submit, class: "btn btn-primary"). If I write class="btn btn-primary" , then error is syntax error  unexpected '=' ...uffer append=( f.submit, class: "btn btn-primary")

Comment: I use it inside. <%= f.submit, options: {class: "btn btn-primary"} %> don't works

Comment: syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting '.' or &amp;. or :: or '['

Comment: I added full view

Comment: @VladimirLozitskiy `<%= f.submit class: "btn btn-primary" %>`

Comment: Oh gosh, I didn't notice it, @Alex thank you